# Show that geometric brownian motion is solution to the stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I want to show that $X_t = X_0 e^{\sigma B_t + \left (\mu - 1/2\sigma^2  \right)t}$ together with $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ and the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq0}$ solves the SDE
$$
X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t \mu X_r\,dr + \int_0^t \sigma X_r \,dB_r.
$$
My idea is to use Itô's formula with the twice continuously differentiable function $F(t,X_t) = \ln(X_t)$, however, how is this done in such a case? Itô's formula is given by:
$$
F(X_t) - F(X_0) = \int_0^t F'(X_r)\,dX_r +  \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t F''(X_r)\,d[X]_r 
$$
Firstly, the quadratic variation of $X$:
\begin{aligned}
\left [ X\right]_t = [\mu \cdot t]_t + [\sigma \cdot B]_t = \int_0^t \mu^2 \,ds + \int_0^t \sigma^2 \, [B]_s = \int_0^t \sigma^2 \,ds
\end{aligned}
Which gives us
$$
\ln(X_t) - \ln(X_0) = \int_0^t \frac{1}{X_r} \,dX_r - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \frac{1}{X_r^2} \sigma^2 \,dr
$$
Tips for proceeding?, I am quite new to Itô's formula and stochastic calculus.

Comment: Make your life simpler and apply Ito to $e^{\sigma B_t\dots}\,.$

Comment: Which gives \begin{aligned}  \exp(\sigma B_t + \left(\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \right) t &= \exp( \mu t- \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2  t )+ \sigma \int_0^t \exp(\sigma B_s + \left(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma \right)s ) \,dB_s \\ &+  \frac{\sigma^2}{2}  \int_0^t  \exp(\sigma B_s+ \left(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma \right)s ) \,ds \end{aligned}

Comment: Not quite. What function $F(t,B_t)$ we apply Ito to? Something is wrong with your partial $t$-derivative.

Comment: Given $F(t,B_t) = \exp(\sigma B_t + \left ( \mu - 1/2 \sigma^2  \right )t) $ We get \begin{aligned} F(t,B_t) &= e^{\sigma B_0 + \left(\mu - 1/2\sigma^2 \right)0 } +  \int_{0}^t e^{\sigma B_{s}+(\mu-1/2 \sigma^2)s} \left( \mu +\frac{\sigma^2}{2} \right) \, ds + \int_{0}^t \sigma e^{\sigma B_{s}+(\mu-1/2 \sigma^2)s} \, dB_{s}   \end{aligned}

Comment: The first term is $1$ and in the second term is a sign error, and the $\sigma^2/2$ term you previously had got lost. One more attempt please.

Comment: \begin{aligned}  F(t,B_t) = 1 + \int_0^t e^{ \sigma B_s + ( \mu - 1/2 \sigma^2)s } \mu \,ds + \sigma \int_0^t e^{\sigma B_s + (\mu - 1/2 \sigma^2) s} dB_s. \end{aligned} This seems correct now, thanks for the help!